# How can I check and create the folder if not existing ? and how can I make that it will take each time one screenshot when pressing the K key?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class HiResScreenshots : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Camera camera;
    public int resWidth = 2550;
    public int resHeight = 3300;

    private bool takeHiResShot = false;

    public static string ScreenShotName(int width, int height)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}/screenshots/screen_{1}x{2}_{3}.png",
                             Application.dataPath,
                             width, height,
                             System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss"));
    }

    public void TakeHiResShot()
    {
        takeHiResShot = true;
    }

    void LateUpdate()
    {
        takeHiResShot |= Input.GetKeyDown("k");
        if (takeHiResShot)
        {
            RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight, 24);
            camera.targetTexture = rt;
            Texture2D screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
            camera.Render();
            RenderTexture.active = rt;
            screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);
            camera.targetTexture = null;
            RenderTexture.active = null; // JC: added to avoid errors
            Destroy(rt);
            byte[] bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
            string filename = ScreenShotName(resWidth, resHeight);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);
            Debug.Log(string.Format("Took screenshot to: {0}", filename));
            takeHiResShot = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting exception DirectoryNotFoundException and when pressing once the k key it's taking screenshots non stop and I want it to take one screenshot each time when pressing the k key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm getting exception DirectoryNotFoundException

You can use [`Path.GetDirectoryName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getdirectoryname#System_IO_Path_GetDirectoryName_System_String_) in order to get the full directory path but without the filename from the `filename`.

And then you can simply use [`Directory.CreateDirectory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.createdirectory)

> Creates all directories and subdirectories in the specified path unless they already exist.

So.you don't even have to check whether it exists. (Of course you still need the permission to do so)

> when pressing once the k key it's taking screenshots non stop and I want it to take one screenshot each time when pressing the k key.

This is a follow up error. Since you get an exception you never reach the line

```
takeHiResShot = false;
```

In general rather use a Coroutine here like e.g.

```
public void TakeHiResShot()
{
    StartCoroutine (ScreenshotRoutine ());
}

void Update()
{ 
    if(Input.GetKeyDown("k"))
    {
        StartCoroutine (ScreenshotRoutine ());
    }
}

private IEnumerator ScreenshotRoutine ()
{
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    
    var rt = new RenderTexture(resWidth, resHeight, 24);
    camera.targetTexture = rt;
    var screenShot = new Texture2D(resWidth, resHeight, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    camera.Render();
    RenderTexture.active = rt;
    screenShot.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, resWidth, resHeight), 0, 0);
    camera.targetTexture = null;
    RenderTexture.active = null; // JC: added to avoid errors
    Destroy(rt);
    var bytes = screenShot.EncodeToPNG();
    var filename = ScreenShotName(resWidth, resHeight);

    var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(filename);
    Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);

    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filename, bytes);

    Debug.Log($"Took screenshot to: /"{filename}/"", this);
}
```

This makes it imposible to land in an endless loop in case there was an error

Comment: It's working but then I found this class : ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(filename); that also working perfect.

Comment: @DanielRurigez possibly but that's not the scope of your question ;)